# Whenever i try to put two differet data on a chart in python, why my Y-axis shows this(as shown in the fig)

Tags: python

```
[plotting two different data on chart][1]   
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGSIr.jpg
```

Whenever i try to put two differet data on a chart in python, why my Y-axis shows this(as shown in the fig)
here is my code:
    import csv
    from datetime import datetime
    with open('sitka_weather_2018_full.csv') as my_file:
      reader = csv.reader(my_file)
      header = next(reader)
      #print(header)
      #for index, column_header in enumerate(header):
        #print(index, column_header)
      dates, maxT,lows = [], [], []
      #this loop is used to get the values from the desired rows from which we want to extract the data
      for row in reader:
        current_date = datetime.strptime(row[2], '%Y-%m-%d')
        dates.append(current_date)
        maxT.append(row[8])
        lows.append(row[9])
    #print(max)
    fig = plt.figure(dpi=64, figsize=(8, 6))
    py.plot(dates,maxT,c='red',alpha=1)
    py.plot(dates,lows,c='blue',alpha=0.5)
    py.title('Temperature in Sitka -- High and low',fontsize=16)
    py.ylabel('Temperature in F',fontsize=16)
    py.fill_between(dates, maxT, lows, facecolor='green', alpha=0.3)
    fig.autofmt_xdate()
    py.show()

Comment: Hi Ali. It would be hard to tell you what's wrong without seeing your code. Please check this link to rephrase your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

You are chosing too many values to be shown on Y-axis. you can use ticks to manage the numbers and names of the point on the axis:

```
yt=np.arange(START,END, step=STEP)
plt.yticks(ticks=yt, labels=names_of_ticks)
```

Comment: what's the value for START and END?

Comment: The limits of y values, that you want to show on your axis. For example if you have values  in range [0,100] and want to show only 5 values you can try: yt=np.arange(0,100, step=5)